# how to incorporate a function within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, range

I updated my code with string dates created with new Date and added back in the if statement. This isn't disabling the string or range though. I've added the datepicker code too.

```
function unavailableDays(date) {

function createDateRange(first, last) {
    var dates = [];
    for(var j = first; j < last; j.setDate(j.getDate() + 7)) {
        dates.push(new Date(j.getTime()));
    }
    var alwaysDisabled = [new Date("1963-3-10T00:00:00"), new Date("1963-3-17T00:00:00"), new Date("1963-3-24T00:00:00"), new Date("1963-3-31T00:00:00"), new Date("1965-9-18T00:00:00")];
    return dates.concat(alwaysDisabled);
}

var disabledDays = createDateRange(new Date("1978-8-10T00:00:00"), new Date("1978-11-5T00:00:00"));

var yy = date.getFullYear(), mm  = date.getMonth(), dd = date.getDate();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
    if($.inArray(yy + '-' + (mm+1) + '-' + dd,disabledDays) != -1 || new Date() < date) {
        return [false];
    }
}
    return [true];
}

$(document).ready(function (){
$('.selector').datepicker({
    inline: true,
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    constrainInput: true,
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: new Date(1940, 1-1, 1),
    maxDate: new Date(2011, 10-1, 24),
    beforeShowDay: unavailableDays,    
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            $("#img").attr("src", "http://www.example.com" + dateText + ".jpg"); 
         var chosenDates = $.datepicker.parseDate('yy-mm-dd', dateText);
         var backToString = $.datepicker.formatDate('MM dd' + ',' + ' yy', chosenDates);
         $('.info').html('You are viewing:' + '<br />' +
             backToString).addClass('background'); 
    } 
});
```

});

Comment: Indenting code properly increases readability.

Comment: You're missing the keyword `function` before `unavailableDays`! Could it be the problem? Aren't you getting an error?

Comment: It's in my page, it didn't copy properly. sorry. Fixed that and the indentation.

Comment: Sorry, but what's the issue exactly? What part works/what doesn't, or what are you trying to get it to do that you need help achieving? Nothing's jumping out at me as a blatant problem...

Comment: The range doesn't work in disabling dates on a calendar. The array is working fine. Now I just need to get them both working together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem in having a function inside of another, JavaScript is pretty much based on that. You could also have separate functions, and it would work as well.

**UPDATE**

(Considering the `date` versus `dates` issue is fixed)

Here is what seems to be the problem (**this is what your question seems to be really about, not functions inside of functions!**): `createDateRange` returns an array of `Date` objects, but your other version (`var disabledDays = ["1963-3-10", ...`) is an array of strings (and in a format that cannot be parsed by `new Date(str)`).

Your current loop seems to be trying to deal with the this string version, and it works, but you want to `createDateRange` to always ignore certain dates (as far as I understand what you are saying). So, try this:

```
function unavailableDays(date) {

    function createDateRange(first, last) {
        var dates = [];
        for(var j = first; j < last; j.setDate(j.getDate() + 7)) {
            dates.push(new Date(j.getTime()));
        }
        var alwaysDisabled = [new Date("1963-03-10T00:00:00"), new Date("1963-03-17T00:00:00"), new Date("1963-03-24T00:00:00"), new Date("1963-03-31T00:00:00"), new Date("1965-09-18T00:00:00")];
        return dates.concat(alwaysDisabled);
    }

    var disabledDays = createDateRange(new Date("1978-08-10T00:00:00"), new Date("1978-11-05T00:00:00"));
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if(disabledDays[i].getTime() == date.getTime()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;

}

// Use `T00:00:00` after the date to set it as GMT, or
// dates can be interpreted as the previous day on some timezones.
var testDate1 = new Date('1978-08-10T00:00:00')
console.log("-- " + unavailableDays(testDate1)); // false
var testDate2 = new Date('1978-08-11T00:00:00')
console.log("-- " + unavailableDays(testDate2)); // true
var testDate3 = new Date('1978-08-17T00:00:00')
console.log("-- " + unavailableDays(testDate3)); // false
var testDate4 = new Date('1963-03-10T00:00:00')
console.log("-- " + unavailableDays(testDate4)); // false
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t4ahF/4/

Comment: That is my problem, yes. I need to disable both array string and range. I updated my code above but added back in the if statement. It makes sense that both date types are being treated the same but it's not working now for either string or range. Could it be that it's something in my datepicker code(see above for update)?And thanks.

Comment: @bklynM, take a closer look at my example code. You are still trying to compare dates with strings when you use `yy`, `mm` and `dd`. My code does it differently.

Comment: the thing is I need to match dates to strings in order to get appropriate images to call up when dates are selected by user. So it has to match yy-mm-dd to get yy-mm-dd.jpg. I'm a newbie so I definitely can be explained out of doing it this way. I just know that the string was disabling the dates but the range wasn't and I don't know how to get the range to 'read' in the unavailableDays so i can use it in beforeShowDays. thanks again.

Comment: I've been playing around with this code and I don't understand why these testsnare not all returning false. 1978-08-11 should also be false as it's in the range between aug and nov '78. The other issue is that my entire datepickers dates are now disabled. thanks.

Comment: @bklynM, `1978-08-11` returns `true` because `createDateRange` does not create the full range between the two dates passed. It takes the first date and create new dates with a one week interval (`j.getDate() + 7`) until the end date. That's what your original code does, I didn't touch that part. As for your datepicker, the problem may or may not be related to that code. You should post a separate question about that.

Comment: thanks. I changed it to 88 which is the number of dates in the range. It still doesn't return them all false. Returns false, true, true and false. The "greying out" of all the dates in the calendar relates to the function. When I hide the line refering to the funciton....beforeShowDays: unavailableDays all the dates come back, including including the ones I had previously hidden successfuly, the string with 1963. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3):

In your function, `dates.push` needs to be `date.push`.

Comment: Sometimes, JavaScript will give you a headache just because of a single character!

Comment: Thanks Scott, I fixed that, but there's still a problem.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems you just want to separate out the functions:

```
function createDateRange(first, last) {
    var date = [];
    for(var j = first; j < last; j.setDate(j.getDate() + 7))
        dates.push(new Date(j.getTime()));
    return date;
}

function unavailableDays(date) {
    var disabledDays = createDateRange(new Date("1978-08-10"), new Date("1978-11-05"));

    //date array to be disabled
    var disabledDays = ["1963-3-10", "1963-3-17", "1963-3-24", "1963-3-31", "1965-9-18"];
    var yy = date.getFullYear(), mm = date.getMonth(), dd = date.getDate();
    for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
        if($.inArray(yy + '-' + (mm+1) + '-' + dd,disabledDays) != -1 || new Date() < date) {
            return [false];
        } 
    }
    return [true]; 
}
```

This will allow you to use `createDateRange` and `unavailableDays` inside another function:

```
function someOtherFunction() {
    var someDateRange = createDateRange(new Date('1979-10-10'), new Date('1980-01-01'));
    … // stuff
}
```

Comment: Putting createDateRange and unavailableDays functions inside someOtherFunction with the variables declared there in addition to above is necessary?

Comment: @bklynM You don't have to put one function inside of another. You *can*, but you make the inner function unavailable to other functions. (Sometimes that's a good thing, but it's not what you want here.)

Comment: How would I include the array in the new function so that it's added to the range in someDateRange? thanks.

Comment: @bklynM Probably by making them arguments to the function.

Comment: like adding...  var someDateArray = createDateArray ["date array"]; and then the same for and if statement as above? New to js so not sure what the argument should say. Any help much appreciated.